# Check for table existance before running sql with Symfony sfPropelMigrationsLightPlugin

Tags: mysql, symfony1, migration

I want to check for the existence of a table before running a create SQL statement in the up() method of a migrate.

I can run something like:

```
$count = $this->executeSQL("SELECT count(*) FROM information_schema.TABLES where TABLE_NAME = 'table_name';");

if($count == 0)
{
   $this->executeSQL("Create SQL ...");
}
```

The problem is that this returns the following error:

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2014 Cannot execute queries while other unbuffered queries are active.  Consider using PDOStatement::fetchAll().  Alternatively, if your code is only ever going to run against mysql, you may enable query buffering by setting the PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY attribute.

Any ideas how to get around this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm dumb...

**IF NOT EXISTS**

```
$this->executeSQL("CREATE TABLE `foo` IF NOT EXISTS");
```